# Does any manuscript provide guidance about what to do with spent up cows

Tags: vedas, rig-veda, yajur-veda, cows, manuscripts

The beauty of our sanatan is that we worship the nature. Cow worship is just an example of it. But now a days, after a cow becomes spent up, ( when the cow is not fit for breeding anymore) they're ending up in slaughter houses. I would like to know if our manuscripts have any solution for this problem.

Comment: Go-Rakshanam = taking care of post-milch and post-draught cows and oxes. Go-Rakshanam does not mean taking care of milk-cows, because that's just a business transaction. There is a verse : a maiden past her beauty, a soldier past his strength and a cow past its milch/draught days must be protected. It's similar to parents - they took care of you when young, now we take care of them when old.